# Cordova/Ionic: How to send Mail

Tags: php, cordova, email, ionic-framework

is there a possibility to send a email in Ionic/Cordova, within my App. I looked at the EmailComposer Plugin, but this seems to just open my default email program. Can Ionic somehow handle php, and whe so, how?

Or if this is not possible, can I send Data, to my Website and store it there?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly send email using php through phonegap. You need to host php in live server, then send data from your app to server's php script and send mail.

If you want to store data in your server(website) you can write some script (in php or asp etc.) to save data into database and call those scripts using AJAX. You'll get tons of materials and tutorials for doing this. These are hints how you can achieve the functionality you wanted, search them and learn them.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery,php mail function to send emails

```
mail('$sender','$receiver','$subject','$message');
```

or

Use AJAX to store data on mySQL DB